# Why each logical CPU has it's own CR3 register in case of multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, x86, cpu

When we have a CPU that supports some form of multithreading, each logical CPU has it's own set of registers (as a minimum), including a CR3 register.

Since we are working on the vitual address space of the same process when executing different threads and a context switch never happens (neither the TLB cache gets invalidated when switching threads of the same process), why do we need a CR3 register to point to the page table and page directory in the logical CPU?

Isn't the value always the same as the value in the CR3 of the physcial CPU?

Comment: The processor doesn't just execute code from one process.  The OS schedules threads.

Comment: @HansPassant Then how is the TLB shared between them? Why it's not invalidated?

Comment: It is not shared, every core has its own TLB.

Comment: So how does memory translation happens when two threads from different processes are running simultaneously?

Comment: They only ever run truly simultaneously when they run on different cores.  Each core has its own CR3 and own TLB, nothing special happens.

Comment: @HansPassant: not quite: logical cores do share the same physical TLB with hyperthreading, but they can still each have separate CR3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since we are working on the vitual address space of the same process when executing different threads

That's not all HT is capable of.  I think you're confusing "hardware thread" (execution context / logical core) with "software thread".

Two logical cores run on one physical core, with one physical iTLB / dTLB / L2TLB.  **The logical cores are very much independent, and don't have to be running threads from the same process.**

This is a desirable property in an [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) design like Intel's HT:  If the OS had to carefully avoid scheduling threads with different page tables onto different logical cores of the same physical core, it would require more synchronization between cores.

---

Two threads of different processes (with separate CR3 page tables) can share one TLB because the entries are tagged with a PCID (process-context ID).  IIRC, hardware virtualization also uses similar (or the same?) tagging to avoid needing TLB flushes on VM exits or when switching between guests.

The OS can set a PCID (low 12 bits of CR3) to avoid needing TLB flushes on context switches, and as a bonus enables concurrent TLB usage by 2 processes.  [Does Linux use x86 CPU's PCID feature for TLB? If not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155304/does-linux-use-x86-cpus-pcid-feature-for-tlb-if-not-why)  (According to that, Linux doesn't generally use PCID, but I assume it does for HT.)

Hmm, I'm not sure I have the details exactly right, but physically there is some kind of tagging of TLB entries to keep them separate even when the two logical cores have different CR3.

---

According to [an Intel forum thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/281287), SnB-family CPUs statically partition the iTLB (so each logical core gets half the entries).  That automatically solves any sharing problems.

The dTLB and L2TLB are competitively shared, so they do need tagging.